# Find the closure of $C=\{f\in C([0,1]):f(0)=0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

> Let $C([0,1])$ be the space of all real valued continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$. Take the norm 
>   $$||f||=\left(\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2}$$
>   and the subspace 
>   $$C=\{f\in C([0,1]):f(0)=0\}.$$
>   Find the closure of $C$.

First, I showed that $C$ is not closed, so it cannot be its own closure. To do this, let's take the function 
$$f_n(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
nx & \text{if } x\leq \tfrac{1}{n} \\
1 & \text{if } x\geq \tfrac{1}{n}
\end{array}
\right.$$
Clearly, $f_n(x)\in C$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. We'll prove that 
$$f:=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \text{if } x=0 \\
1 & \text{if } x\neq 0
\end{array}
\right.$$
To see this, let $\varepsilon>0$ and choose $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3N}}\leq \varepsilon$. Then, for any $n\geq N$ we have that
$$\int_0^1|f_n(x)-f(x)|^2dx=\int_0^{1/n}|f_n(x)-f(x)|^2dx+\int_{1/n}^1|f_n(x)-f(x)|^2dx$$
$$\int_0^{1/n}|nx-1|^2dx+\int_{1/n}^1|1-1|^2dx=\int_0^{1/n}(nx-1)^2dx=\frac{1}{3n}\leq \frac{1}{3N}\leq \varepsilon.$$

Hence, we have constructed a sequence in $C$ which does not converge in $C$ since $f$ is not continuous, so $C$ cannot be closed.

I don't know how to approach the question of finding the closure of $C$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: C([0,1]) is not a complete metric space with respect to that norm.  Are you sure you seek the closure of $C$ in that metric space?

Comment: I know that $C([0,1])$ is not a Banach space, but what is the relation between this and seek the closure?

Comment: The sequence $(f_n)$ you constructed actually converges in $C([0,1])$. You can find a good continuous candidate $g$ for the limit, and then prove that $\|f_n-g\|$ converges to $0$. The same kind of idea should let you solve this problem.

Comment: The function $f$ is *a* limit of $(f_n)$. There are many others, which differ from $f$ on a set of zero measure. In particular, if you take $g \equiv 1$, you can check that $(f_n)$ also converges to $g$.

Comment: But is it something wrong with my proof of $f_n\to f$? Because, if it's correct, $(f_n)$ has a limit which is not in $C([0,1])$, so is not closed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.**

> Let $X$ be a normed space and $f : X \to \mathbb{C}$ an unbounded functional on $X$. Then $\ker f$ is dense in $X$.

**Proof.**
Pick a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $X$  such that $\|x_n\| = 1$ and $|f(x_n)| \ge n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $x \in X$ be arbitrary. Check that the sequence $\left(x-\frac{x_n}{f(x_n)}f(x)\right)_n$ lies in $\ker f$ and converges to $x$.

Now, the functional $\phi : C[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $\phi(f) = f(0)$ is unbounded. Namely, consider the functions $$g_n(t) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{2n - 2n^2t}, &\text{if } t \in \left[0,\frac1n\right]\\
0, &\text{if } t \in \left[\frac1n,1\right]\end{cases}$$

We have $\|g_n\|_2 = 1$ but $\phi(g_n) = g_n(0) = \sqrt{2n}$.

Hence $C = \ker \phi$ is dense in $C[0,1]$, therefore $\overline{C} = C[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

The closure of $C$ in $V=(C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_2)$ is all of $V$. For given $f\in V$, let $f_n\in C$ be obtained from $f$ by $$ f_n(x)=\begin{cases}xf(1/n) \text{ if } x\in[0,1/n]\\ f(x) \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ It's clear that $\|f_n-f\|_2\to0$, so $f$ is in the closure of $C$.